# Filter many-to-many int value with Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

*Using the SphinxAPI in PHP*

I have 2 tables with a many to many relation via a third one. Gamers can attend multiple events.

```
Gamers
- id (UINT)
- username (STRING)
- category (UINT)
- lat (FLOAT)
- lng (FLOAT)

Events
- id (UINT)
- name (STRING)

gamers_events
- gamer_id (UINT)
- event_id (UINT)
```

I saw about MVA with Sphinx, but I am not sure how this is supposed to work.

This is what I have in the gamer index

```
sql_query           = SELECT g.id\
                            , g.username\
                            , g.category\
                        FROM gamer g\
                        /* some LEFT JOIN with other tables */
                        GROUP BY g.id

sql_attr_multi      = uint event from query; SELECT id, name FROM event
```

I am not sure to see how to join the events table to the gamers table.

I would like to SetFilter by the id of events when searching for gamers. Not by name of events, just the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either..

```
sql_query = SELECT g.id, \
      GROUP_CONCAT(ge.event_id) AS event, \
       ...
      FROM gamer g\
          LEFT JOIN gamers_events ge ON (ge.gamer_id = g.id) \
          /* some LEFT JOIN with other tables */
      GROUP BY g.id \
      ORDER BY NULL
sql_attr_multi      = uint event from field;
```

(sphinx can extract it from the column)

OR (sql_query unchanged)...

```
sql_attr_multi      = uint event from query; SELECT gamer_id, event_id FROM gamers_events ORDER BY gamer_id
```

You dont need the events table in either case, just the gamers_events table.

Comment: I went for the concat, it works perfectly! Is there a significant speed difference between the 2 methods? I expect the main table (gamers) to have up to 10.000 entries with 2-3 events each. I also did another concat but with tags this time and gamers have about 5 tags each.

Comment: Oh and by the way why should I put ORDER BY NULL?

Comment: Mysql will by default order the results in the group by order. But sphinx doesnt care what order the rows. So allows mysql to skip the 'sorting' step. Often that is a big overhead, so makes for quicker running query :) Not critical, just a nice to have. (although the mva query if was using that SHOULD have a explicit order by!)